# How do I fix this possibly path related issue of 'List Index Out Of Range'?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a model on my local windows machine for a project and I keep getting the below error for some reason. I have created a new environment on anaconda and installed all the necessary packages for training, but I just can't seem to find what's wrong with this. The code works fine on Colab environment but does not work on Windows local machine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_model.py", line 29, in <module>
    labels = labels_to_number(TRAIN_PATH)
  File "E:\slproject\data_utils.py", line 13, in labels_to_number
    classes = [i.split(os.path.sep)[3] for i in glob.glob(path + '*')]
  File "E:\slproject\data_utils.py", line 13, in <listcomp>
    classes = [i.split(os.path.sep)[3] for i in glob.glob(path + '*')]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here's the data_utils.py file:

```
import glob
import os


def labels_to_number(path):

    print(glob.glob(path + '*'))
    classes = [i.split(os.path.sep)[3] for i in glob.glob(path + '*')]
    classes.sort()

    labels_dict = {}
    for i, label in enumerate(classes):
        labels_dict[label] = i

    return labels_dict


def videos_to_dict(path, labels):
 
    videos_dict = {}
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.relpath(path)):
        for file in files:
            video_name = os.path.join(root, file)
            dir_name = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(video_name))  # label
            videos_dict[video_name] = labels[dir_name]

    return videos_dict
```

and here's a snippet of train_model.py file as well:

```
import os
from itertools import islice

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

from data_utils import labels_to_number, videos_to_dict
from frame_generator import VideoFrameGenerator
from models import create_model_wlasl20c


# model settings
height = 224
width = 224
dim = (height, width)
batch_size = 8
frames = 10
channels = 3
output = 20

TRAIN_PATH = 'E:/slproject/data/train'
VAL_PATH = 'E:/slproject/data/val'
TEST_PATH = 'E:/slproject/data/test'


# transform labels from string to number
labels = labels_to_number(TRAIN_PATH)
print(f'Labels: {labels}')

# load dataset as dict
y_train_dict = videos_to_dict(TRAIN_PATH, labels)
y_val_dict = videos_to_dict(VAL_PATH, labels)
y_test_dict = videos_to_dict(TEST_PATH, labels)

print(f'\nTrain set: {len(y_train_dict)} videos - with labels')
print(f'Val   set: {len(y_val_dict)} videos - with labels')
print(f'Test  set: {len(y_test_dict)} videos - with labels')
print(f'Train set samples: {list(islice(y_train_dict.items(), 3))}')
print(f'Val   set samples: {list(islice(y_val_dict.items(), 3))}')
print(f'Test  set samples: {list(islice(y_test_dict.items(), 3))}')

# get video paths (without labels)
X_train = list(y_train_dict.keys())
X_val = list(y_val_dict.keys())
X_test = list(y_test_dict.keys())

print(f'\nTrain set: {len(X_train)} videos')
print(f'Val   set: {len(X_val)} videos')
print(f'Test  set: {len(X_test)} videos')
print(f'Train set samples: {X_train[:4]}')
print(f'Val   set samples: {X_val[:4]}')
print(f'Test  set samples: {X_test[:4]}')

# instantiation of generators for train and val sets
print('\nTrain generator')
train_generator = VideoFrameGenerator(
    list_IDs=X_train,
    labels=y_train_dict,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    dim=dim,
    n_channels=3,
    n_sequence=frames,
    shuffle=True,
    type_gen='train'
)

print('\nVal generator')
val_generator = VideoFrameGenerator(
    list_IDs=X_val,
    labels=y_val_dict,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    dim=dim,
    n_channels=3,
    n_sequence=frames,
    shuffle=True,
    type_gen='val'
)
```

I tried changing line 13 in data_utils.py to

```
classes = [i.split(os.path.sep)[-1] for i in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*'))]
```

and it still didn't work. Could anyone please tell me what's the issue here and how do I fix it? I would have just run it on Colab, but I want to be able to run on local machine if possible, especially given how poor my internet connection is.

Update 1:

Changed the paths to include backslashes and raw string literals as suggested by and now there's this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_model.py", line 33, in <module>
    y_train_dict = videos_to_dict(TRAIN_PATH, labels)
  File "E:\slproject\data_utils.py", line 38, in videos_to_dict
    videos_dict[video_name] = labels[dir_name]
KeyError: 'above'
```

The error message is indicating that there is a KeyError when trying to access the value associated with the key 'above' in the labels dictionary and that the 'above' key is not present in the labels dictionary, which is strange given 'above' is in the folder and the folder structure is correct: E:\slproject\data\train\above

Update 2:

Additional info for troubleshooting:

result of `glob.glob(path + '*')`: ['E:\slproject\data\train']

result of `i.split(os.path.sep)`: ['E:', 'slproject', 'data', 'train']

result of `glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*'))`: ['E:\slproject\data\train\above', 'E:\slproject\data\train\abroad', 'E:\slproject\data\train\advise', 'E:\slproject\data\train\aeroplane',.........

Any help and advice are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try isolating the problem... What is the result of `i.split(os.path.sep)`? And `glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*'))`?

Comment: @Tim I have added the results to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `result of glob.glob(path + '*'): ['E:\slproject\data\train']`
>
> `result of i.split(os.path.sep): ['E:', 'slproject', 'data', 'train']`

Looks like you need to add a trailing `\` to path, so that `glob` matches the *contents of train* (`train\*` e.g 'train\abroad', 'train\advise') instead of folders *starting with "train"* (`train*` e.g. 'train', 'train2')

```py
import glob
from pathlib import Path

# Simulate train directory
path = Path("train")
path.mkdir()
for cls in ["above", "abroad", "advise", "aeroplane"]:
    p = path / cls
    p.mkdir()
path2 = Path("train2")
path2.mkdir()
    
glob.glob("train" + "*")  # current situation
# ['train', 'train2']

glob.glob("train/" + "*")  # expected result?
# ['train/abroad', 'train/advise', 'train/above', 'train/aeroplane']
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.sep` is system-specific (it's also only barely documented, by reference in the `os` docs for `os.sep`; `os.sep` is the easier to find version), and on Windows, it's a backslash (`\\`). Your hard-coded file paths use forward slashes (`/`). If you're hardcoding the paths, hardcode the separator as well (`os.altsep` also exists on Windows to handle backslashes), or at least make them match.

On "make them match", since these are purely Windows paths anyway, you may as well write them with backslashes and raw-string literals (to avoid doubling every backslash), e.g. changing:

```
TRAIN_PATH = 'E:/slproject/data/train'
VAL_PATH = 'E:/slproject/data/val'
TEST_PATH = 'E:/slproject/data/test'
```

to:

```
TRAIN_PATH = r'E:\slproject\data\train'
VAL_PATH = r'E:\slproject\data\val'
TEST_PATH = r'E:\slproject\data\test'
```

and `os.sep` will match the separator properly.

Note both the change in slash direction *and* the addition of `r` before each literal; if you omit the leading `r`, string literal escapes will be recognized, and your `\t`s will turn into tab characters, while the `\v` will become vertical tabs. *Always* use raw string literals for Windows paths; sometimes it will work without them, but you'll get bit sooner or later when you inadvertently type a valid escape (or invalid, but recognized partial escape like `\U` in `C:\Users` or the like).